# I open the image it's blurry, I zoom in it's sharp either in photo viewer or photoshop

Tags: image-quality

All images I open in photoshop or just in a windows photo viewer look blurry when zoomed out and clear when zoomed in ( honestly I open the image and it's blurry, I zoom in it's sharp). Whats going on?

At the moment, I am stuck and I couldn't find information on this matter. It drives me nuts and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: what equipment are you using to take these images?

Comment: Some screenshots might help in diagnosing this.

Comment: Hi monika, Welcome to photo.stackexchange. Please edit your question to add more requested information and examples.

Comment: I ian, I am using canon 5d mark iii normally 85mm lens

Answer (score 3):

Are you giving the picture time to render fully on your screen before zooming in?  Some systems offer an initial 'preview quality' image in the interests of getting SOMETHING on the screen quickly.

Comment: This reads more as a comment than an answer (and you left out the word 'time'). It could be reworded as an answer as it may be correct.

Comment: Time added, thanks.   Can't be bothered to reword.  As you say, the meaning's clear.

Comment: Laurence, thank you for your comment. I know what you mean by giving enough time for a picture and I do wait enough, but this is something else.

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation could be:

If you open images that are bigger than your screen (or Photoshop/image viewer workspace), the software has to resize [(resample)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling) them to fit in view.

If your workspace is say 1800x1000 pixels and the image is 2400x1600 pixels, the resampling algorithm has to create 5 pixels from the original 8 pixels to fit in screen. The process includes *anti-aliasing* which is a sort of mathematical blurring of the picture to remove [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). Without that, the image would look sharper but ugly "stairs" would be visible on all edges that aren't either 100% horizontal or 100% vertical.

This applies especially while downsampling (making images smaller) in lower ratios (like to 70% of the original image size) and is not such a big problem while downsampling high-resolution images.

The quality depends on the resampling algorithm used. For just displaying an image (not explicitly scaling it on user's demand), usually faster but less precise algorithms are used.

Finally, when you zoom-in to 100% (or 1:1), the original sharp image is displayed without the need of resampling and anti-aliasing, hence looking sharper.

Some programs have an option to use high-quality resampling for displaying images - you may want to check out that option.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I am looking at it right now, checking pixels on my screen  and you might be right with this  'If you open images that are bigger than your screen (or Photoshop/image viewer workspace), the software has to resize (resample) them to fit in view.' I am thinking if thats the case how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any reason that images from a 5D Mark iii (which I also shoot on) would stay out of focus when loading them.  Certainly, when loading initially, Lightroom will often display them in lower quality as it does the RAW processing, but after a second or two, the image should become clear.  If it is not, it sounds like something is going wrong with the software and it might be worth trying either a wipe of your settings or a reinstall?

It may also be that you have some kind of alternate codec being used for rendering the RAW images.  That would be a very odd case, but I'm not sure what else would cause this.  It must be rendering related since it is sharp when zoomed in.

Comment: Thank you, AJ Henderson for your answer. Yes, I am aware of little time that it takes for Lightroom to process images but since I shoot in raw +jpg so I could view pictures quickly in a viewfinder even jpg images are blurry at first and only zoomed in gets sharp.Also I resized my image for web and when I view it its still blurry. I am looking at rendering meaning and what to do next, how to check or fix. I am not quite a computers person so its all a bit difficult for me. Thank you very much for putting me in the right direction.